# how to disable laravel-filemanager from non-admin users?

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have [laravel filemanager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager) v1.7 in my project, and it works fine in administrator side, also images works fine in front-side. but my problem when any registered user (non-admin) or visitor can access laravel-filemanager page by when click on image right-click and open it in new window like:

http://domain/laravel-filemanager/photos/1/593e3d9f3d8fb.jpg

if remove (photos/1/593e3d9f3d8fb.jpg) he can access file manager.

i tried to change config/lfm.php in middlewares but i failed.... how i can disable LFM from any user not admin?

Note: I've middleware called checkRole that check role_id in users table.
I tried to put it in lfm middlewares but it is not work

any help or suggestion?

Regards
Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @btl

I edited (vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/routes.php)

from // Show LFM

until // delete,

i put all of them inside:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'], 'roles' => ['admin', 'supervisor']], function() {
...
});
```

The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to restrict the routes that expose LFM to your non-admin user's. I would probably create a separate middleware that I could apply on a per route or per route group basis to perform this check and deny access.

Another approach could be using Gates and/or Policies to restrict access. You can fine tune it down to the individual user permission if needed.

Comment: I create a separate middleware as you told me, but the images in front-end disappear when visitor or non-admin logged in :(

But i solved the problem in my comment below

Comment: And don't forget to accept the answer and upvotes =D